# JavaScript + Thymeleaf - select onchange

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf

I have a list of objects `services` in my thymeleaf context, and I have the following at my page:

```
<select id="inputService" name="idService" size="1">
    <option th:each="service : ${services}" th:text="${service.name}" th:value="${service.idService}"/>
</select>
<p id="selectedServiceLimits"></p>
```

Each object from `services` contains fields `minAmount` and `maxAmount`. How can I print into my `p` element the these two fields of the selected `service` in `select` by javascript? And how can I print these two fields of the option that is selected when document is ready?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
            /*<![CDATA[*/
            function showLimits() {
                var services = /*[[${services}]]*/ null;
                var selectedIndex = $("#inputService option:selected").index();
                var service = services[selectedIndex];
                $("#amountLimits").text("Мин. сумма: " + service.amountMin + ", макс. сумма: " + service.amountMax);
            }
            $(function() { showLimits(); });
            /*]]>*/
</script>

<select id="inputService" name="idService" size="1" onChange="showLimits()">
```

That's the solution

Comment: This works perfectly for this particular use case. The <p> tag in original question has id of "selectedServiceLimits" so if you go with this solution you should change "#amountLimits" to "#selectedServiceLimits" of the provided javascript to work with your pre-existing html